# Cannot start Kali in Live mode

Tags: kali-linux, live-usb

I have created a bootable usb with the latest Kali version (2016.1), and it works.

In the boot menu (see gif below) if I choose **Live (amd64)** or **Live(amd64 failsafe**) it starts doing something but then it takes me back to the same menu. No way to get it started. Any suggestions?

EDIT: System info:
 Asus N550JK Notebook, where I have windows 8 and ubuntu 14.04 in dual boot (ubuntu was installed from a bootable usb key).

EDIT2 : Got the message that cannot be seen on the gif:

```
Booting kernel failed: Invalid argument
```

[image]

Comment: And what's that 'something'? Does it have any output?

Comment: That bootscreen looks a lot like kali 1.x.  Where did you download the iso? What computer are you running it on?

Comment: The screen is taken from the internet ,it's not the one I'm seeing.downloaded from Kali website and running on an asus n550jk notebook

Comment: @TNW The output is very fast I can't read

Comment: Just to exclude the simplest problem: What CPU your PC is running?

Comment: Intel i7 don't remember the exact version but one of the latest generations  , just to add more info: I have Ubuntu 14.10 installed (to exclude  problems that could be in common with Ubuntu)

Comment: Can you try to film it and then pause the playback and write the text?

Comment: @redfast00 updated the picture with the gif,but I think there is an otuput before returning back to the main screen that my smartphone didn't get.

Comment: @redfast00 also added some system info

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same problem and I fixed it by using parted to change the filesystem label from msdos to gpt.

Open your USB flash drive with parted:

```
sudo parted /dev/sdX
```

Use the `print` command to see what the current filesystem label is. This is what I get:

```
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sdh
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                                
Model: SanDisk U3 Cruzer Micro (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdh: 2048MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  2048MB  2047MB  primary  fat32        boot
```

Notice the partition table is MSDOS. When you use dd to write the ISO to your flash drive, it does not appear to write a partition table with it so you are stuck with whatever format it had before. Anyway, use the `mklabel` command to change the label from msdos to gpt.

```
(parted) mklabel gpt
Warning: The existing disk label on /dev/sdh will be destroyed and all data on this disk will be lost. Do you want to continue?
Yes/No? yes
```

Now use dd to write the ISO to your flash drive and it should boot. At least this worked for me, YMMV.

Comment: For me command `mklabel gpt` in interactive mode of parted doesn't work. German error message is:  `Fehler: Das Argument ist ungültig, während /dev/sdb zum Schreiben positioniert wurde`. I used this command instead: `[root@sirius ~]# parted /dev/sdX mklabel gpt`

Answer (score 1):

the problem in the way you created your live usb !

no doubte you used unetbootin or any other simillar ,

remember for Kali-linux creat your live usb using **dd**

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/kali*.iso of=/dev/sdX
```

where sdX is your usb (sda, sdb ...) NOT a part like /dev/sdX1 !

Comment: Nothing to do, done as you said,same issue. This time i was able to get the error message: Booting kernel failed: Invalid argument

Comment: since kali 1.6 to kali 2.0 sana , i know that kali-linux doesn't work well on a usb even if it work , you won't be able to do any in partitionning step , but when i creat my usb using DD program , i wasn't able to encounter any problem ! and here we have last kali distro which i haven't try yet :)

Comment: please try the light iso image , or better install kali 2.0 sana , because last distro still new, which means it will contain a lot of bugs ...

Answer (score 0):

Your live USB might be corrupt. You might want to try to recreate your live USB using either [Win32DiskImager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/)  on Windows or with `dd` on your Ubuntu install.

Comment: actually it was made with Win32DiskImager, I will try with dd option

Answer (score 0):

1. If you make a usb boot from Windows using [rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/), please use `dd` way to write your iso file to the usb as younes said.
2. No need to enable `legacy boot`. I use thinkpad x220 and still get UEFI on boot.